# Heroku will not update assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Heroku app will not update assets when I push to Heroku, I have exhausted all posts regarding this issue on stack overflow, but nothing works. rake assets:precompile doesn't work either, I have tried deleting the public/assets folder, checked all the config settings in production.rb, and nothing will work. Funny thing is is that it has worked fine for weeks, and for some reason something I did today caused this problem. I know this is vague, I was hoping someone might have some info or suggestions. Thanks, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: did you push public folder on heroku?

Comment: and also check your `git status`

Comment: git status shows many deleted files from the public assets folder, which if I understand correctly are the manifest files.

Comment: If I go through the standard git flow and then run git status after a successful push the files are still present.

Comment: result: Running assets:clean on cornerstone-demo1... up, run.7863
           bash: assets:clean: command not found

Comment: `heroku run rake assets:clean` on `heroku run rake assets:precompile` this is command will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that, perhaps due to reverting a change or otherwise confusing the asset pipeline, your newer assets are considered "older" and are not being used in asset compilation. If so, purging the Heroku build cache via the [`heroku-repo` plugin's `repo:purge_cache` command](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#purge_cache) may help you.

Comment: Thanks, Its telling me I don't have access to my app?

Comment: Make sure you're using the `-a app_name_goes_here` argument with the right app name (check that `heroku apps` returns the list of apps you expect).

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I actually did use the wrong name and ran this, however, the css still isn't updating on Heroku. I keep seeing this: _Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally_, It used to run rake assets:precompile.

Comment: Hmm... did you inadvertently commit your public/assets folder into Git? I'm not sure why else Heroku would be seeing a manifest file already existing, after clearing the build cache.

Comment: So, I just looked in Github and the error files are in the public assets folder. Should they not be?

Comment: The error files (404.html, 500.html, etc), are fine, as is anything else inside `public/` that you truly want to be public and not part of the asset pipeline. There should be no `public/assets` folder, though.

Comment: I know its been awhile but I wanted to thank you for taking the time to try and help me with this. I ended up deleting the assets folder/pushing that change to Github/edited my scss folder/pushing that change/and then finally pushing to Heroku with a successful assets precompile. This was a complete pain in my a--, but I learned a lot from it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should clean your assets folder in /public.

If Heroku detect the 'public/assets' folder he consider you have precompiled your assets locally.